# What's the meaning of "checked out"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is a passage from a [novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ojkGAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y):

> Sometimes Neal would end the conversation or abandon it while she was still making her point, and she'd just go on arguing long after he'd **checked out**.

What does *checked out* mean? I tried looking for the term in the dictionaries, but I couldn't find a definition that fits the context.

Comment: It sounds to me like it means "Neal had checked out of the conversation", i.e. she might keep going on, but he wouldn't be in the conversation any longer. By the way, I think it's *Sometimes Neal would ...*, rather than *Someone Neal would ...*

Comment: Is this in the same "scene" as the other [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69321/meaning-of-clench-in-clenching-the-muscles-in-his-forearms) where Neal was at a counter?  Was he at a register and paid for his items ("check out" [def 2](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/check-out))? More context please.

Comment: @JohnB He's at his own kitchen counter actually. I think Damkerng's explanation is right.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it's the same as this [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23376/whats-the-meaning-of-check-out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be checked out is "to not be paying attention anymore". An alternate meaning is "to not give full effort".

Comment: exactly, with the implication that the ex-listener is thinking about something else without physically leaving the speaker

Comment: @dwilbank correct,